# Content is not cleared when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have two screens.

Screen 1:

It has two edit text fields. And a button.When I press button, it loads, screen 2.

Screen 2:
It has only dummy static text.

Now, when I enter some field and click on button, it loads screen 2. This is desired. However, when I press back button, I should have the edit text fields cleared as it starts calling lifecycle methods from onCreateView.

But, what I found is, it has edit text content lying over there only. It did not clear the text. Debugging the code, made me realize that, putting the break point on the first line of onCreateView, gives the values as entered last time. After that, onCreateView execution, it is initialized with "" and then in resume, it is replaced with the last entered value.

I want to know that reason.

Activity:

```
package com.meditab.testproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements 

BlankFragment.ButtonClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating an object of the Fragment Main Class.
    BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();

    // Fragment transaction to replace the fragment.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frmLayout, blankFragment, "Fragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onButtonClicked() {

    Fragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
    // Fragment transaction to replace the fragment.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frmLayout, fragment, "Fragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Fragment A:

```
package com.meditab.testproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * Use the {@link FragmentA#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private ButtonClickListener buttonClickListener;

public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentA.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentA newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    Button btnClick = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonClickListener.onButtonClicked();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    buttonClickListener = (ButtonClickListener) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}


public interface ButtonClickListener {
    void onButtonClicked();
}
```

}

Fragment B:

```
package com.meditab.testproject;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

public FragmentB() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is the default behavior.
before `onDrestroyView` the view hierarchy state is saved by the fragment manager.

when going `back` the fragment manager restores that state, and that includes the text that was in the edit text.

you can override `public void onViewStateRestored (Bundle savedInstanceState)` to know when the state have been restored. Also note from the docs:

> This is called after onActivityCreated(Bundle) and before onStart().

so, if you really need to clean the state on can do it during `onStart` for example. But remember that in general that is a bad user experience.

Comment: I agree, but when talking about listview items, it clears the list elements.